# How to routing http access to multiple docker container

Tags: docker

How to routing http access for any domain to their specific docker container. So,
any request for:

- web1.mydomain.com is for docker container with id asda912kas
- web2.mydomain.com is for docker container with id: 8uada0a9sd

etc

Every docker container is running apache, mysql, and wordpress or other web apps. web1.mydomain.com and web2.mydomain.com is using same public IP Address (like apache vhost does)

[sorry for my poor english]

Comment: you can try nginx configuration to frontend of your applications. take references from [Deis][1] router and controllers containers functions. [1]: http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/understanding_deis/architecture/

Answer (score 5):

If your web containers are run on the same machine, you can use jwilder/nginx-proxy (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

You run it with port 80 mapped:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

And then you run your web containers with environment variable VIRTUAL_HOST:

```
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=web1.mydomain.com image1
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=web2.mydomain.com image2
```

This works well for small deployments.